# Custom drop down menu animation is scrambled and chaotic?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a custom dropdown menu using swift. I have created the menu and I am trying to animate it.  The animation occurs but the effect of the animation is somewhat scrambled.

Please see in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13BqdYphuCcZAoEV0jG1lyF0k43Pd2JYs/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to get a normal smooth dropdown and pull up effect.  Please can someone advise?

My code:

```
var editButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editTable), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.isHidden = true
    return btn
}()

var createFolderButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Create Folder", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(createFolder), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.isHidden = true
    return btn
}()

var signOutButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Sign Out", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signOut), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.isHidden = true
    return btn
}()

var allButtons: [UIButton]!





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    createDropDownMenu()
    setUpNavigationButton()
    allButtons = [createFolderButton, editButton, signOutButton]
}

private func createDropDownMenu(){

    // StackView
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.alignment = .center

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(createFolderButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(editButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(signOutButton)

    editButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    editButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    editButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    createFolderButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    createFolderButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    createFolderButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    signOutButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    signOutButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    signOutButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
}

private func setUpNavigationButton(){
    // NavigationBar Button
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem.menuButton(target: self, action: #selector(expandMenu), imageName: "expand", navigationBar: navigationController!.navigationBar)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
}

@objc func expandMenu() {
    print("expand menu")
    for btn in allButtons!{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            btn.isHidden = !btn.isHidden // Give value of isHidden the opposite of what is currently is
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [this](https://cocoapods.org/pods/iOSDropDown) pod, it remove most of the headache

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit, I think you will figure out what is happening. The problem was that the stack view resizes itself while content buttons are hidden, may be you need smith like this?

```
   var editButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    return btn
}()

var createFolderButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Create Folder", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    return btn
}()

var signOutButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Sign Out", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    return btn
}()

var allButtons: [UIButton]!

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let stackView = UIStackView()
    private let stackButtonHeight: CGFloat = 50
    private lazy var defTopValue: CGFloat = {
        guard
            let navbar = navigationController?.navigationBar
            else { return 0 }
        return navbar.frame.origin.y + navbar.frame.height
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        allButtons = [createFolderButton, editButton, signOutButton]
        createDropDownMenu()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        stackViewStartState()
    }

    private func createDropDownMenu(){

        // StackView

        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .center

        for button in allButtons {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackButtonHeight).isActive = true
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        view.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    private func stackViewStartState() {
        var frame = CGRect.zero
        frame.origin.y = -CGFloat(allButtons.count) * stackButtonHeight
        frame.size.height = CGFloat(allButtons.count) * stackButtonHeight
        stackView.frame = frame
    }

    func stackViewState() {
        var frame = stackView.frame
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y == defTopValue ? -frame.height : defTopValue
        stackView.frame = frame
    }

    @IBAction func showItmes(_ sender: Any) { // this is your expandMenu
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            self.stackViewState()
            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this for hiding and unhiding with animation

```
func isHidingDropdown(_ flag: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach({$0.isHidden = flag})
        self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```